# Is it possible to get programmatic access to Azure billing info?

Tags: azure

Is it possible to get programmatic access to Azure billing information?

I am aware that you can download a .csv file but that doesn't meet my requirements. I'd really like an API to access the current live billing data.

I can't find anything but I've seen a couple of applications that suggest its possible to do this - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ETs-NgnZV_U.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this tmie it is not.  Quest tools scrap data from HTML of the web-pages afaik

Answer (score 1):

Azure now does provide ways to programmatically retrieve your resource usage and pricing data: https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/new-azure-billing-apis-available

Answer (score 0):

The APIs Moinak refers to seem to be old APIs (we used them before switching to [Azure Cost Management exports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/costs/tutorial-export-acm-data?tabs=azure-portal)).

It seems like there are some new billing apis: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/billing/